# AJAX form submission to MYSQL without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a php code that loops to create multiple separate forms with a submit button for each. I am trying to use JS to update the MYSQL with the form data without leaving the page

The Form (simplified)

```
<form name='myform'>
<SELECT class='index' NAME='album' id='album'>
    <option value='1'>"PUBLIC"</option>
    <option value='2'>"PRIVATE"</option>
    <option value='3'>"FRIENDS"</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="title" size="40" maxlength="256" value="">
<textarea name="caption" cols="37" rows="3"></textarea>
Photo Rating:&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="rate" value="1">ON&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="rate" value="0" checked>OFF&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value="1"> Delete Photo&nbsp;
<?php
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save changes to this photo' onClick=\"picupdate('include/picupdate.php', '1', 'picpg');\">";
?>
</tr></table></form>
```

The JS

```
function picupdate(php_file, pid, where) {
  var request =  get_XmlHttp();     // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance
  var a = document.myform.album.value;
  var b = document.myform.title.value;
  var c = document.myform.caption.value;
  var d = document.myform.rate.value;
  var e = document.myform.del.value;
  var  the_data = 'pid='+pid+'&album='+a+'&title='+b+'&caption='+c+'&rate='+d+'&del='+e;

  request.open("POST", php_file, true);         // set the request

  // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

  // Check request status
  // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

The PHP for updating MYSQL

```
$pid=$_POST['pid'];
$album=$_POST['album'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$caption=$_POST['caption'];
$rate=$_POST['rate'];
$del=$_POST['del'];
$db->query("UPDATE photos SET album = '".$album."', title = '".$title."', caption = '".$caption."', rate = '".$rate."' WHERE pid = '".$pid."'");
```

The reaction on submitting should be the MYSQL updating in the background with no changes to what the user sees. However it is not updating the MYSQL at all.

Comment: You have no error checking or reporting on your query

Comment: Well, what *is* it doing?  You can't just rely on the observed end-result, you need to do some debugging.  Are there any errors from the database?  Any errors in the PHP logs?  What's the response from the AJAX request?

Comment: Yes, I use "error_reporting(E_ALL);" earlier in the PHP. Nothing is reported

Comment: @David all I get in Firebug is 'TypeError: document.myform.album is undefined
 

var a = document.myform.album.value;"

Comment: @StevenVanerp: Well then there you go.  That JavaScript error is in the *second line* of your JavaScript code, so the rest of it isn't running.  This doesn't have anything to do with PHP or MySQL, you have a JavaScript error.

Comment: Yeah kinda figured that out before posting. The question is WHY. Because the 'album' is from a SELECT and not an INPUT? And if so how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by changing the JS to

```
function picupdate(php_file, pid, where) {
  var request =  get_XmlHttp();     // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance
  var a = document.getElementById('album').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('title').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('caption').value;
  var d = document.getElementById('rate').value;
  var e = document.getElementById('del').checked;
  var  the_data = 'pid='+pid+'&album='+a+'&title='+b+'&caption='+c+'&rate='+d+'&del='+e;

  request.open("POST", php_file, true);         // set the request

  // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

  // Check request status
  // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: And for you people that vote down without contributing, GET A LIFE

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not doing anything to prevent the browser from submitting the form when you press the submit button.  There are two ways to do this.  Without using jQuery, you can use the `onclick` property (sort of like what your'e doing), but you have to return a value of `false`, otherwise the form will be submitted *in addition* to whatever the `onclick` handler is doing.  So:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' 
    onclick=\"picupdate('include/picupdate.php', '1', 'picpg');\">
```

Is not doing the trick.  What you need is:

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' 
    onclick=\"picupdate('include/picupdate.php', '1', 'picpg'); return false;\">
```

You can also modify your function, `picupdate` to return false, and then just do this:

```
<input type='submit' 
    onclick=\"return picupdate('include/picupdate.php', '1', 'picpg');\">
```

Lastly, if you want to use jQuery instead, you call `preventDefault()` against the event object when you handle the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="submit"]').on('click', function(evt){
        e.preventDefault();     // prevent form submission
        picupdate('include/picupdate.php', '1', 'picpg');
    });
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried with the JQuery and get an "ReferenceError: $ is not defined $(document).ready(function(){" error in Firebug. And any time I've used input type=submit instead of button, it jumps to my index page when clicked

Comment: If you're getting that error, that's because you haven't linked jQuery in.  Try adding `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` at the top of your document.